Is there an inline way to assert that a value is not None?
I have this code
if foo:
    bar = 1
else:
    bar = maybe_return_int(baz)

The return type of maybe_return_int is Optional[int], so mypy complains
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int | None", variable has type "int")  [assignment]

However, in the context of my code I know that maybe_return_int(baz) will never return None. To get it to type-check, I have to write this tortuous thing:
if foo:
    bar = 1
else:
    bar_maybe_none = maybe_return_int(baz)
    assert bar_maybe_none is not None
    bar = bar_maybe_none

Is there a shorter way to write this? I would like it if there were an assert_not_none function that I could use like this:
if foo:
    bar = 1
else:
    bar = assert_not_none(maybe_return_int(baz))

Could I write such an assert_not_none function?
I could use cast, but I like that assert will actually do the check (at least when assertions aren't disabled) and that with assert I don't have to write the type (in my real code it's a more verbose thing to type than just an int).

I could use cast, but I like that assert will actually do the check (at least when assertions aren't disabled) and that with assert I don't have to write the type (in my real code it's a more verbose thing to type than just an int).

That should be in the question, not a comment. Click the Edit button and add it.

have you tried if foo is not None: instead of if foo:?

(Possible) duplicate: How do I get Pylance to ignore the possibility of None?. This is a very common question, and, yes, we haven't got something similar to TS's !.

@Barmar the question is already very verbose, but sure, done.

@InSync I'm asking a different question. I know how to assert that an expression is not None; I'm wondering if there is a more succinct way to do it. None of the suggestions in the accepted answer do what I'm asking.

(I'm aware that's not a perfect dupe.) You can write your own assert_not_none(), that's for sure: def assert_not_none[T](v: T | None) -> T: if v is None: raise TypeError return v.

assert doesn't "check" anything; mypy just uses it as infer that if it doesn't raise, then the type of bar_maybe_none is narrowed following it. cast exists precisely to override the type checker when you have information (namely, that maybe_return_int won't return None) here, and using it is far more explicit than using assert.

(Assertions can also be disabled at runtime, so you should not rely on them to catch show-stopping errors.)

One alternative, that at least works in mypy, is to say that the type of bar is int | None, and then later assert that it cannot be None. For example:
from typing import reveal_type

bar: int | None
if foo:
    bar = 1
else:
    bar = maybe_none(baz)
    assert bar is not None

# after this if statement, the type checker knows it is impossible for bar to 
# contain None, and so narrows its type to just "int" until such time that it
# might be possible for it to contain None again.

reveal_type(bar)  # Revealed type is "builtins.int"

You can avoid the initial annotation if you invert your if branch so that the initial assignment to bar is of the wider type.
if not foo:
    bar = maybe_none(baz)
    assert bar is not None
else:
    bar = 1
reveal_type(bar)  # Revealed type is "builtins.int"


This is an implementation of assert_not_none:
from typing import TypeVar, Optional

T = TypeVar("T")

def assert_not_none(value: Optional[T]) -> T:
    assert value is not None
    return value

With the above, the following code typechecks:
if foo:
    bar = 1
else:
    bar = assert_not_none(maybe_return_int(baz))

It feels like it would be useful for this to be implemented in some common place (e.g. the stdlib typing module) but it isn't as far as I can tell. I may propose it on the Python Ideas Discourse forum.
